# Why is my responsive, hybrid email template breaking in iPhone 7 Native mail (only)?

Tags: iphone, html-email, ios11, responsive-emails

[iPhone 7 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b77JC.jpg)

The iPhone 7 native email app breaks these stacking rows and doesn't show the background image. This is a hybrid build. The template appears fine in every other device. I’ve included iOS targeting in the head and webkit styles but nothing is working. What could be causing this? Thanks.

```
Here is the full:
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
<!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark only">
<title>Insertion</title>
<!-- The title tag shows in emwail notifications, like Android 4.4. --> 

<!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN --> 
<!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 10 - 27 can be safely removed. --> 

<!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. --> 
<!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
:root {
 color-scheme: light dark;
 supported-color-schemes: light dark;
}
</style>

<!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ --> 

<!-- Web Font / @font-face : END --> 

<!-- CSS Reset -->
<style>
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
html, body {
 margin: 0 auto !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
* {
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table, td {
 mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
 mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
table {
 border-spacing: 0 !important;
 border-collapse: collapse !important;
 table-layout: fixed !important;
 margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
 table-layout: auto;
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
img {
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
*[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */ .x-gmail-data-detectors,  /* Gmail */ .x-gmail-data-detectors *, .aBn {
 border-bottom: 0 !important;
 cursor: default !important;
 color: inherit !important;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 font-size: inherit !important;
 font-family: inherit !important;
 font-weight: inherit !important;
 line-height: inherit !important;
}
/* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying an download button on large, non-linked images. */
.a6S {
 display: none !important;
 opacity: 0.01 !important;
}
/* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
img.g-img + div {
 display: none !important;
}
/* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */
.button-link {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
.nolink-black a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: #000 !important;
}
.nolink-grey a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 color: #222;/*  color: #222 !important; */
}
.mobile-broker {
 margin: 0 !important;
}

/* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
        /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
        /* Thanks to Eric Lepetit @ericlepetitsf) for help troubleshooting */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { /* iPhone 6 and 6+ */
.email-container {
 min-width: 375px !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 374px) {
.email-container {
min-width: 320px !important;
}
}
</style>

<!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
<style>
@supports not (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }
        .fullwidth-left{
            width: 29% !important;
            float: left !important;
            text-align: left !important;
        }
        .fullwidth-right{
            width: 70% !important;
            float: left !important;
            text-align: left !important;
        }
        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .mobile-broker{
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
            .mobile{
                width: 90% !important;
                display: block !important;
                float: none !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            .mobile td, body[data-outlook-cycle] .mobile td{
                width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
                float: none !important;
                padding-left: 0 !important;
                padding-right: 0 !important;
                border: none !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            .mobile td.mobile-padding{
                width: 80% !important;
                padding-top: 30px !important;
                padding-bottom: 30px !important;
                padding-left: 30px !important;
                padding-right: 30px !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            .mobile td.mobile-padding-sm{
                width: 80% !important;
                padding-top: 5px !important;
                padding-bottom: 5px !important;
                padding-left: 10px !important;
                padding-right: 10px !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            .mobile td.mobile-padding .material{
                margin: 0 auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            .two-lines{
                display: block !important;
                float: none !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 599px) {
            td.hero {
            text-align: center !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            background-image: none !important; 
            background-image: url(' https://via.placeholder.com/268x326.png/eee/fff') !important;
            background-size: cover !important;
            background-position: top !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            padding-bottom: 40px !important;
            }
            .sidebar .small {
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }
        .sidebar .large {
            max-width:100% !important;
        }
            
   .two-col {text-align: left;}
            .footer {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            
            
            .fullwidth-left, .fullwidth-right{
                width: 100% !important;
                float: none !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            .mobile{
                width: auto !important;
                display: inline!important;
                float: inherit!important;
            }
            .mobile td, body[data-outlook-cycle] .mobile td{
                float: inherit!important;
                border: none;
                text-align: left !important;
            }
            .mobile-center{
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            .mobile-hide{
                display: none !important;
            }
            .mobile-padding{
                padding: 30px 20px !important;
            }
            .mobile-header{
                font-size: 23px !important;
                line-height: 28px !important;
                text-align: left !important;
            }
            .width52{
                width: 52% !important;
                border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9 !important;
                padding: 0 20px 0 0 !important;
            }
            .width48{
                width: 48% !important;
            }
        }
        }
        .nocenter{
            text-align: left !important;
        }
        .link-blue a{
            color: #073a66 !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }
    </style>
<style>
#MessageViewBody, #MessageWebViewDiv{
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
}
#MessageViewBody .email-container, #MessageWebViewDiv .email-container{
    width:100% !important;
    max-width:100% !important;
}
#MessageViewBody .mobile td.mobile-padding-sm, #MessageWebViewDiv .mobile td.mobile-padding-sm{
    width: 80% !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
</style>
<style>
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

  

      /* Custom Dark Mode Background Color */
      .darkmode {
        background-color: #100E11 !important;
      }
      .darkmode2 {
        background-color: #000000 !important;
      }
         .darkmode3 {
        background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
      }
      .outline { border-color: #333333 !important; }

      /* Custom Dark Mode Font Colors */
      h1, h3, li{
        color: #000000 !important;
      }
      h2, a {
        color: #f5f5f5;
      }

    .dmtext3 {color: #8cd6f2 !important;}


      /* Custom Dark Mode Text Link Color */
    .dmtext { color: #000000 !important; }
    .dmtext2 { color: #f5f5f5 !important; }
        
      .link { color: #00aeef !important; }
     .footer a.link{ color: #00aeef !important; }
     .footer { color: #f5f5f5 !important; }
    }
    /*.nolink-grey {color: #8cd6f2 !important;}*/

    /* Copy dark mode styles for android support */
    

    /* Custom Dark Mode Background Color */
    [data-ogsc] .darkmode {
      background-color: #100E11 !important;
    }
    [data-ogsc] .darkmode2 {
      background-color: #000000 !important;
    }

    /* Custom Dark Mode Font Colors */
    [data-ogsc] h1, [data-ogsc] h3, {
      color: #000000 !important;
    }
   
      [data-ogsc] h2, [data-ogsc] li, [data-ogsc] a {
        color: #fdfdfd !important;
    }

    /* Custom Dark Mode Text Link Color */
    [data-ogsc] .link { color: #028383 !important; }
    [data-ogsc] .dmtext { color: #000000 !important; }
    [data-ogsc] .dmtext3 { color: #8cd6f2 !important; }
    [data-ogsc] .footer a.link { color: #fdfdfd !important; }
    
  </style>

<!--correct superscripts in Outlook--> 
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <style>
          sup{font-size:100% !important;}
        </style>
        <![endif]--> 

<!-- What it does: Makes background images in 72ppi Outlook render at correct size. --> 
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body class="darkmode" width="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
<center class="darkmode" style="width: 100%; background: #e0e0e0; text-align: left;">
 <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
 <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</div>
 <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --> <!--
            Set the email width. Defined in two places:
            1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 680px.
            2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 680px width.
            Note: The Fluid and Responsive templates have a different width (600px). The hybrid grid is more "fragile", and I've found that 680px is a good width. Change with caution.
        -->
 <div class="email-container" style="width: 100%; max-width: 680px; margin: auto;"><!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td width="680">
            <![endif]--> <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
  <table class="email-container" style="width: 100%; max-width: 680px;" border="0" width="680" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
   <!-- HERO : BEGIN -->
   
   <tbody>
   
   <tr>
    <td class="darkmode2" style="background: #fff; padding: 40px 35px; border-bottom: 8px solid #073a66;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/251x90.png/09f/fff" alt="Hextone" width="251" height="auto" border="0"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="hero darkmode3" style="text-align: center; background-position: center top !important; background-size: cover !important;" valign="top" height="380" bgcolor="#ffffff" background="https://via.placeholder.com/680x440.png/09f/fff" align="center"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
               <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 680px; height: 554px;" src="https://materials.proxyvote.com/Approved/IMAGES/20200612/LOGO_434678.JPG" />
               <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 680px; height: 380px;">
                  <v:fill opacity="0%" color="#333333" />
                  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                     <![endif]-->
     
     <div><!--[if mso]>
                            <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680">
                            <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="500">
                            <![endif]-->
      <table style="max-width: 500px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="dmtext" style="padding-left: 20px;" valign="middle" align="center"><table width="100%">
           <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td style="text-align: center; padding: 40px 0px 15px 0px;" valign="top" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="left"><table width="90%" align="left">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td class="dmtext" style="text-align: left; padding: 0 20px 15px 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000;" valign="top"><p style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0;">{{{CURDTYY}}} |<br>
                   <span class="dmtext" style="white-space: nowrap;">Your account ending: {{{ACCT}}}</span></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td style="text-align: left; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;" valign="top"><h1 class="dmtext" style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 28px; line-height: 36px; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">Your Prospectus<br>
                   Document(s) are<br>
                   available online as<br>
                   a result of your recent<br>
                   transaction(s).</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td style="text-align: left; padding: 15px 20px 0 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #000000;" valign="top"><p class="dmtext" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; margin: 0;">Please click on the link(s) below<br>
                   to view your document(s).</p></td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td style="text-align: center; padding: 15px 0px 40px 0px;" valign="top" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
<td style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
</tr> -->
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!--[if mso]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]--></div>
     
     <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                        <![endif]--></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- HERO : END --> <!-- INTRO : BEGIN -->
   <tr>
    <td class="darkmode2" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
      
      
      <!--  <tr>
                                   <td role="presentation">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr> -->
      <tr class="container center-text">
       <td class="details darkmode2" style="padding: 10px 20px; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
          <!--{|{URLS_LOOP}|}-->
         {!if not empty(URLS_LOOP)!} {!each URLS_LOOP!} {! if loop_var.URL != '' and loop_var.URL !} {! if loop_var.CUSIPN == 'INSERT DOCUMENT:'!}
         <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom: 1px #DEDEDE solid;" valign="middle"><table class="account" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td  width="380" valign="middle" height="80"><span class="dmtext3" style="font-size: 18px; color: #073a66;">{{{loop_var.FNDNAME}}}</span></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
           <table class="button" style="margin: 0 auto;" border="0" width="180" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td width="180" valign="middle" height="80" align="center"><table align="center">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td style="margin: auto; background-color: #073a66; color: #f5f5f5;  padding: 5px 10px; width: 150px;" valign="middle" align="center"><a style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; text-decoration: none; color: #f5f5f5;" href="{{{loop_var.URL}}}">View Document</a></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table></td>
         </tr>
         <!-- ***DISPLAY INSERT*** -->{!else!}
         <tr>
          <td class="darkmode2 dmtext" style="border-bottom: 1px #DEDEDE solid; background-color: #ffffff;" valign="middle"><table class="account" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td width="380" valign="middle" height="80"><span class="dmtext3" style="font-size: 18px; color: #073a66;"> {{{loop_var.FNDNAME}}}</span> <br>
               <span class="dmtext2" style="font-size: 14px; color: #303030;">CUSIP: <span class="nolink-grey dmtext3" style="font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none !important; color: #303030;">&zwnj;{{{loop_var.CUSIPN}}}&zwnj;</span></span></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
           <table class="button" style="margin: 0 auto;" border="0" width="180" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td width="180" valign="middle" height="80" align="center"><table align="center">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td style="margin: auto; background-color: #073a66; color: #f5f5f5; padding: 5px 10px; width: 150px;" valign="middle" align="center"><a style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; text-decoration: none; color: #f5f5f5;" href="{{{loop_var.URL}}}">View Prospectus</a></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table></td>
         </tr>
         {!end!} {!end!} {!end!} {!end!} <!--{|{URLS_LOOP}|}-->
         
         </tbody>
         
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
      <!-- PROSPECTUS SECTION -->
      <tr>
       <td class="darkmode" bgcolor="#073a66" style="padding:20px;text-align:left; background-color: #073a66;"><table class="darkmode" style="background-color: #073a66;margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td><div class="spacer" style="line-height:20px;height:20px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="sidebar" style="font-size:0;text-align:center;direction:ltr;"> 
             <!--[if mso]>
                                                                            <table role="presentation" width="100%">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                            <td style="width:100px;padding:10px;text-align:center;" valign="middle" dir="ltr">
                                                                            <![endif]-->
             <div class="small" style="width:100%;max-width:100px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
              <div style="padding:10px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;"> <img src="https://materials.proxyvote.com/Approved/IMAGES/20181129/LOGO_377124.PNG" width="80" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:80px;height:auto;" /> </div>
             </div>
             <!--[if mso]>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width:460px;padding:10px;text-align:center;" valign="middle" dir="ltr">
                                                                            <![endif]-->
             <div class="large" style="width:100%;max-width:460px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;direction:ltr;">
              <div style="padding:10px;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;color: #ffffff;text-align: left;">
               <h2 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:12px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;">Prospectus Document? What's that?</h2>
               <p class="dmtext2" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:14px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;letter-spacing: .5px;">A prospectus document is a legal document that outlines your investor rights and explains the investment strategy of the fund you're invested in.</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <!--[if mso]>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                                                            <![endif]--> 
            </div></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
      
      <!-- END SECTION -->
      
      <tr>
       <td class="footer darkmode2" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;" valign="top" align="left"><!---
                                             Place your customized legal stuff here-->
        
        <p class="dmtext2" style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; color: #444444;">{{BRPOBOX}}<br />
         Please do not respond to this e-mail as this mailbox is not monitored and cannot generate a reply. <br>
        </p>
        <br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="background-color: #e0e0e0;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      
     </table></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- INTRO : END -->
   
   </tbody>
   
  </table>
  <!-- Email Body : END --> <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]--></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show a screenshot of what you are expecting, too. This code snippet is only part of the whole...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are expecting, but it looks like something is out of alignment.

Running a code linter shows that you are missing a `</tr>`, which may have caused this.

This part:

```
</table></td>
</tbody> <!-- should be </tr></tbody> -->
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
</td>
</table>
<![endif]--></div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nathan, thank you, for calling out the missing ```<tr>``` tag. Since that is the code for Outlook, it's not effecting this layout break.  Above my question is the image of the problem, the blue link that says: "iPhone 7 screenshot." I am adding the full code below.

Comment: Well, you've picked up another one, but there is also a missing `</tr>` before the conditional mso (see the comment - it's above the mso).

Comment: However, this is all good on the updated code

Comment: I am mistaken, the iPhone 7 iOS is 14. Yes! I believe there was an unnecessary style "white-space: nowrap;" was throwing the cell alignment off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your code has changed, my previous answer no longer relates.

There are two issues here: 1, the weird positioning; and 2, the background-image not working.

The background-image doesn't appear to be supported until iOS 12.
See https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background/, https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-position/, and https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-size/. You use all of these, but support starts from iOS 12

I can't test iOS 11 / iPhone 7 so I'm not sure what's going on. Is there any way you can post the resultant code, i.e. from the iPhone?